# Sentence Structure and punctuation

Tags: punctuation, syntactic-analysis

Is this correct? I am unsure if I should put a colon or semi-colon instead of a comma before "but" in the following sentence:

> In this appeal, the question is not “What would I have done had I been
>   in the Respondent’s shoes?”**[,](http://jsutforhiglight.com)** but rather “Was the Respondent’s decision
>   patently unreasonable?”

Answer (score 1):

It is correct.

"But" is a [coordinating conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(grammar)#Coordinating_conjunctions) which connects the parts that pose a contrast. The part after your comma is not a sentence and cannot stand on its own; therefore, using a colon or semi-colon seems inadvisable.